# Adding listener to an editor grid panel

Tags: extjs

There is an Editor grid panel.
I am trying to add a listener to the cell click event.  I have tried to do it in different ways:

```
gridPanel.addListener('cellclick',myfunction);
```

inside the grid:

```
listeners: {
    cellclick: myfunction
}
```

I have tried to do it in the selectionModel object.
None of them worked.
Where can be the problem?

Comment: Which version of extjs do you use?

Comment: try listeners:{'cellclick':function(){alert('a')},scope:this}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't add the listener as a config parameter, it's probably because you're having problems with the callback function not being in scope, similar to this:

```
> var obj = { greetMe: this.sayHi, sayHi: function(){ console.log('hi'); }};
undefined

> obj.greetMe();
TypeError: Property 'greetMe' of object #<Object> is not a function

> obj.greetMe
undefined
```

In the first line, `this` was still referring to the global (read: window) object at the time the object was defined.  So `this.sayHi === window.sayHi === undefined`.  The same thing happens when you define Ext config objects.  Try defining the callback inline:

```
> var obj = { greetMe: function(){ console.log('hi'); }};
undefined

> obj.greetMe()
hi
```

Other options:

1. Define the function in a wider scope, outside of your class
2. Attach the listener within the constructor or within initComponent, by which time your class methods should be instantiated
3. Attach the listener sometime later

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `cellmousedown` of grid panel or cell `selectionchange` of selection model.

Comment: It doesn't help. I think the click event doesn't get the cell

Answer (score 0):

addListener worked. I had some syntax error.
Still adding the listener as a parameter doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

For row selection I put it on the selection model and for double clicks on the grid directly. This works well but I must warn you if you don't prevent the default event you will get horrible memory consumption.

Ext.onReady(function(){

```
requestGrid.getSelectionModel().on('rowselect', handleRowSelect);
requestGrid.on('rowdblclick', handleDoubleClick);
```

}

It would help if I read :) My solution is for row selection not cell selection but it might very well work.

Comment: I tried the onReady function, but it couldn't get the grid. I think it was executed after the html loaded, but before the javascript. Maybe it was not the problem, but it didn't work anyway.